# Minimum Spanning Tree in R (vegan): managing identical values

Tags: r, data-mining, text-mining

In R the package "vegan" contains the function [spantree](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/vegan/docs/as.hclust.spantree).
It takes a matrix of distances among terms and it creates a tree with all the points... unless two or more rows (ex: A, B, C) are identical.

[image]

In that case only one term (ex: B) among the identical ones is plotted and linked to the tree. The other points (A, C) are represented outside the tree.

[image]
I know I could link the identical terms as one. For example, if the terms "Lazio" and "Forza" are identical (same distances from all the other terms) I could take only one term ("Forza_Lazio") instead of two, but I don't like this solution very much.

How can I solve this problem? Are there other R packages managing this (not that rare) case?

Comment: There is nothing to solve - the points simply share the node on the tree - the tree itself will not change.

Comment: But two points with the same distances from the others will be represented differently: one possibly linked to the other nodes, the other disconnected. I would expect like a node with two labels.

Comment: Are you just talking about the actual data visualization? Just add in the extra data labels however - maybe have a different point symbol if there are coincident nodes. The underlying tree structure won't change though. I don't understand what your *statistical* question is.